# Python for loop initialization of reference to function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this sample code where I expected it to print the current test.x variable, but when I use a for loop for defining a list of function references I am not getting what I'm expecting([1,1] and [0,0]). I do get what I'm expecting when I use the commented lines instead ([0,1] and [1,0]). I realize that there are easier ways to do this but for my program I need it to be the way it is but I want to define the rules object in a for loop instead of defining each element on a line because I don't know how large the rules object will be. Thanks for any help (Python 2.7)

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = list([0, 1])
    def get_value(self, i):
        return self.x[i]

test = TestClass()
rules = list([None, None])
for a in range(2):
    rules[a] = lambda t: test.get_value(a)
#rules[0] = lambda t: test.get_value(0)
#rules[1] = lambda t: test.get_value(1)

print(rules[0](0), rules[1](0))
test.x[0] = 1
test.x[1] = 0
print(rules[0](0), rules[1](0))
```

Comment: Why would you copy.copy a 0 and a 1?

Comment: I think the problem is rules[0] and rules[1] are both calling test.get_value(1) and I thought copy.copy might help but it isn't

Comment: You tagged the question python 2.7, but your code appears to be python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be shown more concisely as follows:

```
>>> rules = list([None, None])
>>> for a in range(2):
...   rules[a] = lambda t: a
... 
>>> rules[0](0)
1
>>> rules[0](1)
1
>>> rules[1](0)
1
>>> rules[1](1)
1
```

I think the problem is that the code always reflects the final value of `a`.

This is known as "late-binding closures" and is discussed in the [Python Guide here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

One (rather ugly) way of getting round this is to create the new function each time by partially applying a function using the `functools` package. This "captures" the current value of `a`.

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> for a in range(2):
...   def get(t,x): return x
...   rules[a] = partial(get,x=a)
... 
>>> rules[0](0)
0
>>> rules[0](1)
0
>>> rules[1](0)
1
>>> rules[1](1)
1
```

A simpler way of achieving the same effect:

```
>>> for a in range(2):
...   rules[a] = lambda t,a=a: a
```

As shown in the linked Python Guide, you can also use a list comprehension to simplify the code a little:

```
rules = [lambda t,a=a: a for a in range(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Though it can be simplified with partial(lambda t, x: x, x=a)